# UIViewController leaving Space in bottom

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I am upgrading an old project from iOS4 to latest ios8. There are 2 or three view controllers that don't look right, the navigationbar seem to cover portion of the view and also leaving space in the very bottom. I can't seem to figure it out no matter what I changed for settings by removing/adding topbar/statusbars/bottombars, the xib file looks alright, but not when I run it on simulator or device. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I see this right, it is an UIImageView holding the backgroundimage... ?!?

I can only guess, but you should change the UINavigationBarStyle from translucent to opaque... That will bring everything lower, where it was supposed to be.

Comment: I changed to opaque but no difference. As a matter of fact I I set to None, translucent, opaque, inferred, neither made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Click on this viewController in Storyboard, uncheck the box for "Under Top Bars" and check the box for "Under Bottom Bars" in the Extend Edges Settings. This should solve your problem!

Comment: It's not checked, none of the extend edges properties are checked.

Comment: You you using size classes or auto layout?

Comment: I think you need to right click on your storyboard, and open as source code. Look for the properties you are trying to change in there. I believe there's still a bug in XCode 6 with projects that used auto layout with a previous version. You will probably have to change it in the XML source code.

Comment: No autolayout and no storyboard, its a xib. I attached more settings in original question.

Comment: Have you tried changing all the Simulated Metrics to "inferred"?